# How to use google search api in python to search data from csv file and then write back findings to cvs

Tags: python, csv, google-api

I have a cvs file which have addresses and I want to search these addresses in google and find associated company names to them and right back those findings to cvs. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: well, what api calls have you tried?

Comment: @Fallenreaper I just started learning python and I am using google search API where I am able to get URL only from the address but don't know how to extract company name from that

Comment: I cant help you without code.  I will not solve your problem for you.  I can only guide you through your mistakes.